# Insert unique_ptr in vector as pair

Tags: c++, vector, stl, unique-ptr, std-pair

I have following vector:

```
std::vector< std::pair< std::unique_ptr<CEdit>, CRect >> m_editCtrls;
```

I'm trying to insert here some data:

```
std::unique_ptr<CEdit> edit = std::make_unique<CEdit>();
CRect rectEdit;
//Init edit....
//1 - This doesn't work
std::pair< std::unique_ptr<CEdit>, CRect > pair = std::make_pair<std::unique_ptr<CEdit>, CRect>(std::move(edit), rectEdit);
//2 - This also
m_editCtrls.insert(std::make_pair(std::move(edit), rectEdit));
```

In first case I'm getting error - `no instance of function template`, in second - `no instance of overloaded function`.

Which is the proper way to insert this pointer into the vector?

Thank's for help.

Comment: Impossible to tell without knowing the definition of `CRect`.

Comment: does `insert` work without an `iterator` pointing to the location of insert?

Comment: `Crect` and `CEdit` are standard controls MFC classes.

Comment: [Don't write the template parameters in `std::make_pair`](https://youtu.be/AKtHxKJRwp4?t=2932)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't pass template arguments to `std::make_pair`. Just let them be deduced. See [this video(link)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AKtHxKJRwp4&feature=youtu.be&t=2932) by Steven Lavavej. (thanks to Passer By for finding the link)

```
std::pair<std::unique_ptr<CEdit>, CRect> pair = std::make_pair(std::move(edit), rectEdit);
```

`std::vector` does not have a function named [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) that only takes one argument. You have to pass an iterator for a position. Perhaps you were looking for `push_back`?

```
m_editCtrls.push_back(std::make_pair(std::move(edit), rectEdit));
```

Or even better, `emplace_back`.

```
m_editCtrls.emplace_back(std::move(edit), rectEdit);
```